# Rosetta Stone Code Challenge

Tags: code-golf, rosetta-stone

I presume you've all heard of the [Rosetta Stone](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone), an ancient stone found to have essentially the same passage written on it in three different scripts. This challenge is based upon that: you have to write three versions of the same program in ***different*** languages.

The three programs must output the first `n` [iban numbers](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_number), `n` being a number input by the user. There are only 30,275 iban numbers, so **if `n` is *greater* than 30275, the program should return an error.**

The challenge of the Rosetta Stone was that the scripts didn't appear to be [mutually intelligible](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility)–knowing one didn't automatically make the others understandable. Your three programs should similarly be mutually unintelligible. That is, you may not golf down a Python 2 program and then submit it (or a minor modification) as a Python 3 version too, nor a C program as C++, etc. To prevent this, the [Levenshtein distance](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between any two versions should be at least 25% of the length of the shorter of the two versions being compared, and at least 16 as an absolute numerical value. You may check conformance using this online [Levenshtein distance calculator](http://planetcalc.com/1721/).

The winner is the person with the shortest combination of programs.

Comment: I retagged the question. I replaced code-golf with code-challenge because your scoring is not purely by code size. I also removed the rosetta-stone tag. While your challenge is clearly inspired by the Rosetta Stone and is also about writing code in multiple languages, the rosetta-stone tag explicitly indicates that answers should be written in *as many languages as possible* which is not true for this challenge.

Comment: Upvotes+codelength? Highest score? do you really want huge bloated programs? Upvotes-codelength would be better. Also is that codelength for one program or all three?

Comment: @steveverrill it *is* `-length`

Comment: What should the output be if `n > 30275`?

Comment: The first time around, I read "iban number" as IBAN number, unfortunately.

Comment: On a separate issue, mixing objective criteria with popularity seems like a way to get the worst of both worlds. If a question has an objective criterion, [it should be scored on that criterion and not on popularity](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1985/194).

Comment: Are there restrictions on using 3rd party libraries and such?

Comment: @Danny You can use whatever you want

Comment: I think you can save this problem by making the scoring strictly objective. The "popularity" scoring is usually a last resort for fun problems that are otherwise impossible to score.

Comment: Does C# and Java count as a valid combination? (I don't wanna start any arguments, just wondering)

Comment: Originally this was scored by "shortest longest program" of the three, now it just says "shortest program". May I suggest "shortest total length of the three programs"? "Shortest program" to me means golf it down in one language and the other two don't matter.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I actually think this one can be fun. It's a *real* rosetta stone challenge.

Comment: Also, "and so on..." is pretty vague. Unless you can give a full list of banned combinations, people are going to have to just hope their choices aren't banned together. For instance, you ban python 2/3, but don't mention java 6/7/8. I can *assume* that's banned, but what about Java/Groovy, or Javascript/Coffeescript?

Comment: Do we have to include the *entire* program? e.g. `int main...` or can we just include the good stuff?

Comment: @Geobits You can't expect me to list them all!

Comment: @Milo Yeah, exclude the required stuff

Comment: @BetaDecay What about banning the versions of the same language, and supersets (e.g. C++ and C or Objective-C and C), *and* each program has to differ by at least 10 characters (excluding variable names)?

Comment: @BetaDecay Without a clear list you're telling people to guess/hope what combinations are valid. Just in the comments so far, I've asked about two combinations, Milo has asked a couple, and you haven't answered *either*. So yea, I can expect you to list them all. Either that or find some better way to describe what makes a pair of languages banned (probably the better option).

Comment: @Geobits Hey, sorry, I haven't been online to reply. Anyway, I've edited the question to using Milo's suggestion of language families and difference of 10 characters.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret *The winner is the person with the shortest program.*, given that every answer must contain three programs. If we just look at the shortest of the three, it doesn't make much sense to post the other two. Also, in what universe are Bash and Batch similar languages?

Comment: @Dennis They're vaguely similar... And about the winning criteria, that has become diluted and *nonsensical* over time due to suggestions from various people. It seemed alright at the time.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide a way of easily verifying conformance with the spirit of the question, but had to invent thresholds. I think they're reasonable but you may want to tweak them, @BetaDecay.

Comment: @comperendinous That's brilliant thanks, I'll leave it as it is

Comment: Im afraid there isnt much choice in strategy to generate the numbers and three required languages for each entry pretty much forces duplicates or few submissions.

Comment: @comperendinous adding the Levenshtein distance was a really nice effort but I fear it might not be thorough enough, just swapping the order of some things will easily do to get around any reasonable threshold.

Comment: When was this reopened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 424 <s>425</s>: Haskell, Python 2, Perl

As they should for a true Rosetta comparison, all three programs work the same way, taking input from the first command-line argument and building up the list with the same rules, and variable names, where possible.

### Haskell, 171

```hs
import System.Environment
main=do i<-getArgs;putStr.show$[n|n<-[0..777777],all(`notElem`"5689").show$n,all(\d->n`div`d`mod`100`notElem`13:[30..39])[1,1000]]!!(read.head$i)
```

### Python 2, 156

```py
import sys
print[n for n in range(777778)if all([c not in"5689"for c in str(n)])and all([n/d%100not in[13]+range(30,40)for d in[1,1000]])][int(sys.argv[1])]
```

### Perl, 97 <s>98</s>

```pl
$i=@ARGV[0];die if $i>30275;for(0..777777){push@n,$_ if!(/[5689]/ or/(13|3.)(|...)$/)}print@n[$i]
```