# Generate Eban Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

(Continuing on the number sequences code-golf, here is an interesting sequence)

Eban Numbers ([A006933](http://oeis.org/A006933)) are the sequence of numbers whose names (in English) do not contain the letter "e" (i.e., "e" is "banned")

The first few numbers in the sequence are:

```
2, 4, 6, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56
```

Given an integer `n`, via function argument or STDIN, return the first `n` terms of the Eban Numbers (in numbers) .

Since some answers will involve some sort of string check for character `e`, assume that the maximum value of `n` can be such that the `nth` Eban number is less than 1 Quadrillion.

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/rosetta-stone-code-challenge

Comment: Searching questions on this site is pretty primitive ... Anyways, Eban numbers are more tricky than Iban in so many ways :)

Comment: Do the terms have to be output numerically, or may they be output as words?

Comment: Yes, numeric output.

Comment: Are we allowed to use modules off CPAN that aren't in the core if doing a Perl solution?

Comment: Anything is fine, just call it out and tell how to test it. (like what to install etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### <s>Mathematica</s> CJam, <s>108</s> <s>95</s> <s>46</s> <s>35</s> 30 bytes

**Edit:** Ported to CJam! The original and ungolfed Mathematica code is at the bottom and explains the algorithm quite well.

```
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=0s*ip}/
```

And now I know CJam. :D Thanks to Dennis for some golfing improvements.

After analysing them a bit to determine how many there are below one quadrillion, I came to the conclusion that all eban numbers are basically base-1000 numbers using only a set of 20 digits:

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 60, 62, 64, 66
```

So we enumerate them by converting the input to base 20, picking the right digit from the set and build a base 1000 number from it.

This is how the code works in detail:

```
li                             "Read from STDIN, convert to integer n";
li,                            "Turn into a range array [0 ... n-1]";
li,{                        }/ "For each number execute a block";
li,{)                       }/ "Increment";
li,{)K                      }/ "K is initialised to 20, push that";
li,{)Kb                     }/ "Convert to base 20";
li,{)Kb65430s               }/ "Push a string with possible multiples of 10";
li,{)Kb65430s2046s          }/ "Push a string with possible least significant digits";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*        }/ "Take the Cartesian product of the two character
                                arrays, generating the 20 'digits'";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$       }/ "Sort the result";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=     }/ "For each digit in our base-20 number, get the
                                base-1000 digit from the list";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=0s   }/ "Push a '0' character";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=0s*  }/ "Join all the digits, with that '0' as the delimiter";
li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=0s*ip}/ "Convert to an integer and print the result";
```

Here was the original Mathematica code, which doesn't encode the digit list and is hence fairly readable:

```
{0,2,4,6,30,32,34,36,40,42,44,46,50,52,54,56,60,62,64,66}[[IntegerDigits[#,20]+1]]~FromDigits~1000 & /@ Range @ # &
```

Comment: Unprintable characters would work just fine. You can replace `20` with `K`, `1000` with `1e3`, `{i41-}%` with `41f-` and `{")+-/GIKMQSUW[]_aegik"41f-=}%` with `")+-/GIKMQSUW[]_aegik"41f-f=`. Futhermore, the array (string) could be pushed as `[4U5Z6][U4Y6]m*Afb$` (`m*` is Cartesian product, `$` is sort), for a total of 33 bytes (35 if you prepend `li` to read from STDIN).

Comment: @Dennis I knew I was missing out on a lot of good tricks, thanks! ;) I just remembered that CJam happily deals with large bases so I quickly wanted to throw something together, because I figured this could beat all other answers. I'll go through your tips and work them in when I understand why they work. :)

Comment: You can save 5 more bytes by using strings instead of numbers, eliminating the need for the last two base conversions: `li,{)Kb65430s2046sm*$f=0s*ip}/`. Unfortunately, `'ﾖis'०is` has the same byte count as `65430s2046s`.

Comment: @Dennis Interesting. What's the difference between `/` and `%`?

Comment: Doesn't really matter here, just force of habit. `%` collects the results in an array, so it leaves an empty array on the stack here. Since those aren't printed, it would only matter for a function.

Comment: @Dennis oh right "each" vs "map" should have clicked.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash+coreutils+[BSDGames](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games) package, <strike>79</strike> 70 bytes

```
seq $[9**16]|while read n
do number $n|grep -q e||echo $n
done|sed $1q
```

Unfortunately this spawns `number $n|grep -q e` for every number, so is rather slow.

#### Output:

```
$ ./eban.sh 5
2
4
6
30
32
$
```

---

#### Previous answer - outputs words instead of digits, 43 bytes

```
seq $[9**16]|number -l|grep -v [e.]|sed $1q
```

This outputs each term written in words:

```
$ ./eban.sh 5
two
four
six
thirty
thirty-two
$
```

A bit faster, because each process is only spawned once.

---

## Much faster, no dependence on cheaty `number`, 77 bytes

```
t=0{0,3,4,5,6}{0,2,4,6}
eval echo $t$t$t$t$t|tr \  '
'|sed "s/^0*//;$[$1+1]q"
```

This one uses [bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate all (according to my thinking) eban numbers up to 10^15.  Looking at each group of 3 digits, the units digit must be one of {zero,two,four,six}, the tens digit must be one of {zero,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty}, and the hundreds digit must be zero.  Since *x*-illion contains no e's up to quadrillion, then
we can just combine the groups of three digits up to one quadrillion.  The only exception is zero which must be skipped.

So we simply build a brace expansion to generate all these numbers.  There are thus 20<sup>5</sup>-1 of them (3.2 million).  Evaluating the full bash brace expansion takes less than 5 seconds on my VM.

The `sed` expression just strips off leading zeros and counts to n.

#### Output:

```
$ time ./eban.bash 5

2
4
6
30
32

real    0m4.065s
user    0m3.724s
sys 0m0.276s
$ ./eban.bash 10000000 | wc -w
3199999
$ ./eban.bash 3199999 | tail -5
66066066066056
66066066066060
66066066066062
66066066066064
66066066066066
$
```

Comment: Will this first generate 10^15 numbers and then stop at $1 ? or incrementally check and stop generating after 5th number ?

Comment: @Optimizer `seq` can generate that many numbers, but because this is all a long pipeline, whenever any one of the processes quits, the shell will send a SIGPIPE to all processes in the pipeline, and thus they will all quit.  In this case, the `sed $1q` will quit after the nth line it receives, and thus the rest of the pipline will be torn down, before `seq` can count much further (modulo buffering in each pipe).

Comment: I think you can probably play around and print the actual number instead of the English version. Maybe via awk/sed.

Comment: please do it...

Comment: That sounds fast. Although, I am not getting any output on my MINGW32. It runs and prints a new line.

Comment: @Optimizer looks like MinGW uses an ancient version of bash (3.1.17) which doesn't support the {start..end..step} brace expansion.  I've edited the answer slightly at a cost of zero extra bytes to use a different form which I think should work.

Comment: Now it just throws : `eban.sh: xmalloc: cannot allocate 8 bytes (0 bytes allocated)` and online compilers timeout. I'll be okay if anyone else can confirm that the faster approach is correct

Comment: @Optimizer Looks like that old bash version has poor memory management.  If you're serious about testing the more Linuxey answers, I recommend you install some distro (Ubuntu is easy) in a VM.  Virtualbox and VMWare player are free, I think.  Another thing you can try for this answer is replace `$t$t$t$t$t` with `$t$t$t$t`.  With this the script will work with numbers up to 1 trillion.

Comment: That helps and now I can see the output. It really is fast.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>128</s> <s>121</s> 119 bytes

```
f=->n{a=[]
i=0
(j=i+=2
b=p
(m=j%t=1000
b=b||m%2>0||m%10==8||m>9&&m<30||m>69
j/=t)while j>0
a<<i if !b)while a.size<n
a}
```

I'm basically just checking groups of three digits for numbers that contain `e`s, because none of `{thousand, million, billion, trillion, quadrillion}` contains an `e`.

Comment: You can safely do `i+=2` as all numbers in Eban numbers are even

Comment: @Optimizer lol yeah, since I have a `m%2>0||` I was even aware of that. :D thanks!

Comment: Can you probably find out `n` where it crosses a quadrillion ? I don't have the setup and online compilers won't run for that big `n`

Comment: @Optimizer Not with the program. I'd need an optimised version which skips over thousands/millions/etc if the offending "e" comes from one of the more significant digits. But if I'm not mistaken, there should be Σ(n=1...5) 19^n = 2,613,659 eban numbers below a quadrillion.

Comment: @Optimizer I think I was mistaken. I think it should be 20^5-1 = 3199999 eban numbers below a quadrillion instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl - 78

Here is a Perl one-liner to do it.

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Numbers=num2en -nE'while($n<=$_){$n++&&say$i if num2en($i)!~/e/;$i++}' <(echo 5)
```

It is 50 characters plus 1 for the `M`, 1 for the `n`, and 26 for `Lingua::EN::Numbers=num2len`.

Using [Lingua::EN::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua::EN::Numbers) from CPAN. Here are [instructions](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) for installing CPAN modules.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 66 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.25 bytes

```
Þ∞'∆ċ\ec¬;Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiw57iiJ4n4oiGxItcXGVjwqw74bqOIiwiIiwiNyJd)

Bitstring:

```
001001110101101011111000111110011011000101110000000110101001010010
```

```
Þ∞'∆ċ\ec¬;Ẏ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Þ∞           # ‎⁡infinite list of integers
  '      ;   # ‎⁢filter by
   ∆ċ\ec¬    # ‎⁣cardinal of the number does not contain 'e'
          Ẏ  # ‎⁤slice to length of input
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [6.125 bytes: `∆ċ\e$F)ȯ`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oiGxItcXGUkRinIryIsIiIsIjQiXQ==) ([vyncoded](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md))